# Bad file descriptor error from the read end (2 pipes which inter-communicate)

Tags: c, pipe, fork

```
if (pid != 0)                           // server
{

    read(fd_client_to_server, word1, sizeof(word1));    // parent reads the word sent by the client
    printf(" I received this command...%s\n", word1);

    // the server will write the word to the CP

    if (strcmp(word1, "read login : username") == 0 || strcmp(word1, "quit") == 0 || strcmp(word1, "logout") == 0 || strcmp("get-logged-users", word1) == 0 || strcmp("get-proc-info", word1) == 0) // if one of these commands, communicate through pipe
    {
        close(p1[0]);
        if (write(p1[1], word1, sizeof(word1)) == -1)   // write the command for the CP
            perror("Can't write in the pipe\n");
        printf(" 2 I received this command...%s\n", word1); // correct
        close(p1[1]);

        wait(NULL);                     // I will wait the CP until it send me back some data

        **                              // / HERE IT DOESN'T WORK PROPERLY***
            close(p2[1]);
        if (read(p2[0], word2, sizeof(word2)) == -1)
            perror("Can't read from pipe\n");
        printf("4 I received this command...%s\n", word2);
        close(p2[0]);

        write(fd_server_to_client, word2, sizeof(word2));

    }
    else {
        printf("%s", "The server can't do this yet!");
    }

}
else {                                  // CP

    close(p1[1]);
    if (read(p1[0], word3, sizeof(word3)) == -1)    // it is stuck here until smthng appears to be read
    {
        perror("Can't read from the pipe!");
    }
    printf(" 2 I received this command...%s\n", word3);
    close(p1[0]);

    if (strcmp(word3, "quit") == 0)
        strcpy(word4, "yay!");

    close(p2[0]);
    if (write(p2[1], word4, sizeof(word4)) == -1) {
        perror("Can't read from the pipe!");
    }
    printf(" 3 I received this command...%s\n", word4);
    close(p2[1]);
}
```

I commented where the error exactly occurs. The array called "word4" has the correct data in it. I tried to even change the body of the processes with other properly-working code I had which were not a client-server model but it still doesn't work. I have to send the received data from the CP back to the server, which is going to send it back to the client... The error which I get is `**Bad file descriptor**` and it loops forever...Full code:
server.c: https://onlinegdb.com/-p-w8o5id
client.c: https://onlinegdb.com/ZIWC3DQVF

Comment: A quick look ... (e.g.) You use `read` on `word1`. Then, you do `strcmp`. Note that `read` will _not_ append a 0x00 which string functions like `strcmp` need. Better to use `memcmp` or add your own 0x00. But, you're _not_ checking/using the return value from `read`. I'd post more of your code. (e.g.) definitions of `word1` et. al. And, the calls you make to `pipe` and `fork`. Ideally, a small but full program in a single code block that compiles cleanly, links, and is downloadable and runnable by others here.

Comment: @CraigEstey I added my full code here: server.c https://onlinegdb.com/-p-w8o5id, client.c: https://onlinegdb.com/ZIWC3DQVF

Comment: A quick synopsis of the code that highlights the error: `while(1) { read from pipe; close pipe; }`. You can't read from the pipe after you close it.  If you want to read in a loop, don't close it inside the loop.

Comment: William is correct. In the server, you are doing (e.g.) `if (pid == 0) { close(p1[0]);` _inside_ the loop. Yes, you _do_ want to close the "other" end of the pipe. On the second loop iteration, this is wrong but harmless. Should be done _above_ the loop, but, not fatal. But, you also do `write(p1[1],...); close(p1[1]);` Which is bad. You really want to only do `close(p1[1]);` _after_ the loop. Similar for the parent case (but reversed).